# What is an unambiguous single word for a five-pointed star without enclosure?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that describes this thing (1):

[image: 5-pointed star with internal lines]

but not this thing (2):

[image: 5-pointed star with internal lines and enclosing circle]

The obvious choice here would be **pentagram**, but in colloquial use, that word unfortunately refers to both (1) and (2), as well as a number of variants of (2) that have other enclosures surrounding the 5-pointed star. (In mathematical use, "pentagram" uniquely refers to (1) and not (2), but I am not writing for a mathematical audience, so that's still a no-go.) It also has connotations I would like to avoid (devil worship, goat sacrifice, etc.).

If all else fails, I can just call (1) a "five-pointed star", but that gets to be a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: Funny, I just ran across a passage in a Harry Dresden novel that relied on exactly this precise distinction between a pentagram and a pentacle. And I had to read it like three times to get it straight, even though I was aware of the difference. So this is an apt question, I think.

Comment: It's a satan worshipping star-thingy. You are out of luck :)

Comment: @mplungjan no, it's the first star I learned to draw :-)

Comment: @mplungjan, in a number of dodgy B movies, and presumably other clutural references, an inverted pentagram is associated with the occult. However, I aslo recall its use in other films like, Schindler's List. I know which I regard as the better movies.

Comment: From my observation above we may infer some level of anti-semetism is pre-modern culture.

Comment: The stars in Shindler's list will have been the two overlapping triangles called a David's star. Anyway I was trying to be funny

Comment: You could put dashes in "rotationally-symmetric-stellate-pentagon": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_pentagon#Stellated I'm pretty sure there's only one such object, and it's the one you supplied.

Comment: Note that in some situtaions "Sheriff's Star" can help here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To reiterate what you described, in strict usage the following apply:

This is a **pentagram** – a type of **five-pointed star**

[image]

This is a **pentacle** – a **pentagram** circumscribed by a circle:

[image]

This is a **five-pointed star** that is *not* a pentagram:

[image]

Yes, as you described, strict usage is not always the case, and when you say **pentagram** it evokes **pentacle** in the minds of many people. However, I am convinced that there is no single word that is both common and unambiguously understood to mean the first case. I am assuming that since you consider **five-pointed star** "a bit of a mouthful" that you mean to repeat this term at least a few times in whatever you're writing. If I were in your place, I would use the term **pentagram** (since after all, it is correct in formal usage), and use a picture to show the reader exactly what you mean. If you are writing in a medium where you cannot use pictures, I would spend a sentence to describe it as a five-pointed star drawn with five straight strokes.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia, it *is* a [Pentagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram).

Wikipedia points out that [Pentacles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentacle) are magical objects and

> despite the sound of the word, often had no connotation of "five" in the old magical texts, but were, rather, magical talismans inscribed with any symbol or character.

Comment: Interesting note about pentacles!

Answer (score 1):

Doczi in 'The Power of Limits' p 6, viewable [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Power-Limits-Proportional-Architecture/dp/1590302591/), distinguishes between a pentagon, a pentagram and a **pentagonal star** (this last (highlighted in bold) refers to your (1) above). Unfortunately it's 2 words, not 1.

Comment: -> "pentastar" to coin something (you'll probably find a better neologism but I doubt you'll find a single word that's unambiguous without defining it)

Answer (score 0):

If you must avoid *pentagram* then consider:

- pentacle
- pentalpha
- pentangle

see: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pentagram

Or in some cases you could just say *star*.

Isn't the occult/demonic pentagram upside-down — rotated 180 degrees?

Knowing more would help. What is the context? Who is the audience? Why are you seeking this one word label?

Comment: Nice answer Box73

Comment: 'Isn't the occult/demonic pentagram upside-down — rotated 180 degrees?' -- No, it is only rotated 72 degrees.

Comment: @Lighthart ITYM 36.

Comment: Oh, math fail by Lighthart!  Shoover is correct.

Comment: @Lighthart Well, there's an infinite number of solutions in the form of: 36 + 72c for any integer c.

Comment: I have to apologize for inadvertently turning this in to stackgeometry.

Comment: I was just looking at the "Stars" symbol section of Unicode yesterday. They refer to a 5 point star (without interior lines) as a "star", and for all other point counts, that's part of the name ("6 point star", etc.).

Comment: *Pentacle* unambiguously refers to a pentagram inscribed in a circle, so using that word would accomplish exactly the opposite of the request in the question.

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of being banished from the site for eternity for language bending, what about `pentapoint`?

Disclaimer: `pentapoint` is ***not*** an English word.

Answer (score -2):

pentastar or pentalpha would be correct answers.

Comment: Do you have some source that says these are English words?

Comment: penta is not an English word. It comes from greek and widely used in English. And you anyway know that "star" is an English word.